# How to correlate instance id and activity invocation id in azure java duration function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm writing a java duration function.  My purpose is to make it traceable, eg, there's an id for me to look up all related logs.  I have not found anything useful, then I'm thinking about the id returned to client.

In the http trigger, When it creates a orchestration instance, it generates an instance id as well which is then returned to client.

I have several activity functions.  From `ExecutionContext`, I can get the `InvocationId`.

Is it possible to to correlate this `InvocationId` with the `instance id`?